# Why does std::map::erase return int rather than bool?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

I wonder why `std::map::erase` has an overload that returns an `int` that represents the number of elements erased; so as long as the elements are unique so the number is either `1` or `0`. In this case why it doesn't return `bool` rather than an `int`?

```
     std::map<std::string, std::size_t> containers{
    {"map", 1}, {"set", 10}, {"map", 5}, {"vector", 4}, {"array", 7}
};

for(auto const& p : containers)
    std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << '\n';

std::cout << containers.erase("map") << '\n'; // 1
std::cout << containers.erase("map") << '\n'; // 0

for(auto const& p : containers)
    std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << '\n';
```

Comment: It's probably for consistency with `std::multimap`, whose `erase` method can remove more than one element at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question becomes obvious once you consider what [`std::multimap::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/erase) returns.

That container's `erase()` method might return 0, it might return 1, or it might return some other value.

Having an interface that's consistent across containers allows for implementation of templates and algorithms that work equally well with either container, since the return value from `erase()`, whether it's from a `map` or a `multimap`, means exactly the same thing.

P.S. Without looking it up, you should be able to make a pretty good guess what `std::set`'s and `std::multiset`'s `erase()` methods return.

Comment: So they return `int` too, don't they?

Comment: no, they return `size_type`.

Comment: @user1095108: Yes I did mean it. Anyway an integral type reporting the number of erased elements.

Answer (score 0):

All the c++ ordered associative containers are based off of a binary search tree, are related, and this is reflected in their similar interfaces.